# Need help in a school programming internal

Tags: c#, combobox

I have two lists called `standards` and `credits`. The `standards` list is added to a `ComboBox`. When I click an item in the `ComboBox` I want to be able to show an item in the `credits` list. For example I click first index in the `ComboBox`, I want to show item in the first item of the `credits` list. I have this code but it gives me an error I can't fix it. This is the error im getting:

> System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException

It's from this line of code

```
lblCredits.Text = credits.ElementAt(standard.IndexOf(cboStandard1.Text))
```

-

```
    private void cboStandard1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (cboStandard1.SelectedIndex + 1 > 0)
        {
            lblCredits.Text = credits.ElementAt(standard.IndexOf(cboStandard1.Text));
        }
    }
```

This is showing that my lists are the same length

```
    private void standardlist()
    {





        standard.Add("91632");
        standard.Add("91633");
        standard.Add("91634");
        standard.Add("91635");


        cboStandard1.DataSource = standard;

        ((ComboBox)cboStandard1).SelectedIndex = -1;

        credits.Add("4");
        credits.Add("6");
        credits.Add("4");
        credits.Add("4");



    }
```

Comment: This is bad: `cboStandard1.SelectedIndex + 1 > 0`. That should be `cboStandard1.SelectedIndex != -1` or `cboStandard1.SelectedIndex >= 0`.

Comment: You don't need `ElementAt` if `credits` is an array, a `List<T>` or anything else that implements `IList`. `ElementAt` is just for things that don't an indexer of their own.

Comment: You should post the error here so we can help you. Further I think your error is within `credits.ElementAt(standard.IndexOf(cboStandard1.Text));`

Comment: You don't need to get the item from the `ComboBox` and use that to get the index from the `standard` list unless the `ComboBox` contains different items or in a different order. If they're in sync, just use the `SelectedIndex` of the `ComboBox`.

Comment: Yea im new to programing but the 2 lists are different

Comment: Don't tag your question with VB.NET unless it's specifically a VB.NET question.

Comment: The error i am getting is from that lblCredits.Text = credits.ElementAt(standard.IndexOf(cboStandard1.Text)); code and it says system.ArgumentOutOfRangeException

Comment: Don't put information like the error message in a comment. Edit your question and put it where it belongs.

Comment: That error message suggests that `credits` and `standard` have different numbers of items, so how can you possibly assume that any index in `standard` will also exist in `credits`? You need to first understand the relationship between the two lists and then implement that relationship in code.

Comment: I just counted the lists and there is the same amount of items. I get this error when i first start my program

Comment: I must have missed where you explained that this happened at startup in the first place.  Debug your code, which you should already have done.  Here's what I'm guessing is happening: you're populating `standard`, binding that to the `ComboBox` and then populating `credits`. If that is the case, the binding causes the first item to be selected, which causes the `SelectedIndexChanged` event to be raised, which executes your code. If that happens before `credits` is populated then, just as I said, the lists are not the same length.

Comment: Maybe that's not what's happening though. We can only guess because we're getting information in dribs and drabs and you don't have all the information to give because you haven't debugged.

Comment: Yea ive tried all sorts to fix this problem and i literally on just starting to learn this, and i have researched for hours trying to find out how to fix this and sorry if im giving bad information, but i think i have given all information. I just added more code to question to show lists are the same length.

Comment: Put a breakpoint (`F9`) at the line where the exception occurs, run the program in debug mode, then mouse-over the `credits`, `standard` and `cboStandard1.Text` to see what's going on.

Comment: I just debugged that line like you said. I got a credit count of 0 standard and cboStandard1.text count of 16. Where is my problem? im dumb asf

Comment: Then @jmcilhinney was probably right - try filling `credits` before you assign something to `cboStandard1.DataSource`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like I said, binding the `ComboBox`, i.e. setting its `DataSource` property, will select the first item by default, which will raise the `SelectedIndexChanged` event, which will execute your code. That all happens before you've populated the `credits` list, which is why it contains no items.  There are two things you can do, and you may choose to do both:

1. Populate the `credits` list before setting the `DataSource` of the `ComboBox`.
2. Handle the `SelectionChangeCommitted` event instead of `SelectedIndexChanged`.

The `SelectionChangeCommitted` event is raised only when the user selects an item via the UI, so it will not be raised when you bind the data and then reset the `SelectedIndex`, while `SelectedIndexChanged` will be raised twice.  Even if you do implement option 1, you'll still have an issue on the second `SelectedIndexChanged` event because you'll be passing -1 to `ElementAt`, so you'll get an `ArgumentOutOfRangeException` thrown.

Comment: Thank you so much, this actually made my day cause i was stressing about it, and now i know where i went wrong :)